# Different set of labels for the same counter name?

Tags: prometheus

I am thinking to do something like this:

```
counter_name counter 
sample_name_of_that_counter_name_1 {'key1'="value1"} 12 
sample_name_of_that_counter_name_2 {'key1'="value8",'key2'="value2","key3"="value3"} 23
sample_name_of_that_counter_name_3 {'key4'="value4"} 2
```

So the same counter as a metric name will have different sets of labels (as keys as values) and as consequence different series.

But reading documentation I am confused.
In one place it says (https://prometheus.io/docs/concepts/data_model/#metric-names-and-labels):

```
"Every time series is uniquely identified by its metric name and optional key-value pairs called labels. "
```

-so looks like I can create a counter "counter_name" with label: key1 => value1 and it will create this time series determined by counter_name + label.
And another unique series will be created with using the same counter name but different labels: counter "counter_name" with labels: "key1 => value1, key2 => value2"

Then later it confirmed by doc:

```
"Changing any label value, including adding or removing a label, will create a new time series."
```

But on another page (https://prometheus.io/docs/instrumenting/writing_clientlibs/#labels) in the same documentation we see:

```
"Client libraries MUST NOT under any circumstances allow users to have different label names for the same metric for Gauge/Counter/Summary/Histogram or any other Collector offered by the library."
```

It confuses that "if client adds or removes label - it will create new time series (for the same metric name)" - but in the same time "it MUST NOT be allowed."

Could anybody help to figure out here please?

Comment: Having different label names for a metrics is unorthodox. Usually, you would rather define multiple metric names. What is the rational ?

Comment: I did consider that way but really think that in my case I want the same metric with mutable labels, also I started to curios about that since the php lib I use kind of allows to save that unorthodox case but trow an exception while expose. Here how I came to the mutually exclusive statements in the documentation and now trying to figure out. And if it's not allowed why then the documentation says : "Changing any label value, including adding or removing a label, will create a new time series."? That's is exactly what I need - same metric with different labels..